# InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error: in inference part (transformer for timeseries model using tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, time-series, transformer-model

in the inference part, when i want to predict the sequence of values using a transformer model within for loop , i have this InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error: and i couldn't resolve it. the main thing that i couldnt understand is that the shape for first valie is (none,1,1) [batch size, time steps, features)] for first iteration but for the second iteration, instead of (none,2,1) i had (none, none,1)

## this is inference code:

```
def run_transformer_inference( input_sequence): # input_sequence must have 3 dimensions [batch size, time_steps, n_in_feature]

  #get encoder output
  encoder_output = encoder_model.predict(input_sequence)


  #take last time step value of the input sequence, to be decoder input in first iteration of the loop below
  decoder_input=input_sequence[:,-1,:]  # shape = [batch size, n_out_feature]
  decoder_input = np.expand_dims(decoder_input ,axis=1)  # shape = [batch size,1, n_out_feature]

  print("first at all decoder input shape ", decoder_input.shape)
  print("encooder ", encoder_output.shape)

  #out_seq=np.array([])
  #out_seq = decoder_input.copy()

  for _ in range(out_win):
    print("iteration ", _)

    # Make prediction
    prediction = decoder_model.predict([decoder_input ,  encoder_output ])
    #print("predction shape ",prediction.shape)

    # Obtain the predicted value at step t+1 (last predicted value )
    last_predicted_value = prediction[:, -1, :] # shape = [batch size, n_out_feature]

    last_predicted_value =np.expand_dims(last_predicted_value,axis=1)  # shape = [batch size,1, n_out_feature]
    #print("last_predicted_value ",last_predicted_value.shape)

    #if _ == 0 :
      #out_seq = last_predicted_value
    #else:
      #out_seq = np.append(out_seq,last_predicted_value ,axis = 1)
    #print(out_seq.shape)
    #decoder_input = np.concatenate(decoder_input,last_predicted_value)
    decoder_input  = np.append(decoder_input,last_predicted_value ,axis = 1)

    #decoder_input = last_predicted_value
    print("decoder input shape ",decoder_input.shape)

  return out_seq
```

every iteration, the number of steps add one value untill i predict the whole sentence, thats why in the input shape of decoder i choose it to be none for the timesteps as you can see in the code below

as you can see in the message output for first iteration iteration 0 decoder output (None, 1, 1) after slicing pos enc (1, 512) xhile in next iteration iteration 1 decoder output (None, None, 1) ( i need it to be (None, 2, 1) ) after slicing pos enc (256, 512) ( i need it to be ( 2, 512) )